# Where is the GPU?

Tags: debian, nvidia, graphic-card

Installed Debian 7.5.0 on Asus X550LD-XX028 (http://www.flipkart.com/asus-x550ld-xx082d-notebook-4th-gen-ci7-8gb-1tb-free-dos/p/itmdvyg4krwqgaes), with Nvidia GeForce 820M. The nvidia-detect (https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/nvidia-detect) command didn't detect any NVIDIA GPU.

Can someone please explain what is happening ?

Comment: What is the output of `lspci -n`?

Comment: How did you install driver? NVidia binary or package manager? What's the output of `lspci |grep -i vga`?

Comment: @ILMostro_7 `nvidia-detect` is a script to *determine* which driver package to install, which one is installed doesn't matter.

Comment: These appear to be the drivers for that GPU: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/70744/en-us

Comment: This is what `lspci` has to say about the NVIDIA device "04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
"